# How to disable authorised socket.io connection?

Tags: azure, socket.io

I am using socket.io and azure pub sub. We want to allow only specific domain to connect. We want to check the domain if exist or not form a redis store. If it exist we can allow connection otherwise we want to reject.. Here is what we tried but didn't work...

```
    import express from "express";
    import http from "http";
    const app = express();
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    import { Server } from "socket.io";
    import { useAzureSocketIO } from '@azure/web-pubsub-socket.io'
    import url from 'url'
    import Redis from "ioredis";
    import dotenv from "dotenv";
    dotenv.config();
    const redis = new Redis();

    const io = new Server(server, {
        cors: {
        origin: "*",
        },
    }); 
    // Use the following line to integrate with Web PubSub for Socket.IO
    useAzureSocketIO(io, {
        hub: "Hub", // The hub name can be any valid string.
        connectionString: process.env.AZURE_SOCKET 
    });
    
    
    io.use(async( socket, next) =>{
        const origin = socket.request.headers.origin
        if(!origin) {
        return next(new Error('unauthorized'))
        }
        // Extract the hostname from the origin
        const parsedUrl = url.parse(origin);
        const hostname = parsedUrl.hostname;
        // console.log('host name is ', hostname)
        const school_id = await redis.get(hostname) 
        console.log('school_id', school_id)
        if(!school_id) {
        console.log('school_id not found', hostname)
        console.log('REJECTING....')
        return next(new Error('unauthorized'))
        }
        return next()
    
    
        
    });
    
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        /// allow connection
    });
```

It says connected but it never capture any data. if I remove io.use middleware, it works again.. How can we achieve it?